# Formatting a number in a TextBox onBlur and onLoad ? using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-kendo

I have a view with text-box of type Number and i am successfully validating whether i'm entering numeric's or not like that using knockout validation plugin

But here comes a situation where i need to format my entered numbers with a `comma` for every four digits `onBlur` (millions formats) .

I have no clue how to proceed with this implementation but i just had couple of thoughts but no idea how to make it into picture (better ideas are appreciated)

Here is my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/78/)

**Requirement :** I will explain my scenario based on this number `1234567890`

1. onLoad i need to show the number in my textbox as `12,3456,7890`
2. If user wants to modify the number means when he clicks inside the text-box the number should become `1234567890` so he can modify it (onblur sort of).
3. After modifying if user clicks outside the text-box means the number should become comma separated to view .
4. Finally i have validation to check whether is it number or not . #so it should accept numbers with comma .

**I thought something like this :**

1)i use computed to format and return it

2)no clue on this but gave a thought to subscribe

3)same subscribe

4) custom validation separating commas in a number and validating i.e may be regex expression .

Is it even possible in knockout or not i have my doubts but fingers crossed i hope everything has some way .

Interestingly i found [**knockout-kendo**](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/NumericTextBox.html) which does the work what i'm looking for but i prefer  to implement the same functionality in knockout rather using some other plugin which cause issue in some point of time .

Any ideas are crazy enough for me to run .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two inputs:

- Input 1 is readonly & visible by default and contains the formatted value.
- When Input 1 is clicked, hide it, show and focus Input 2 with the real value that can be edited.
- When Input 2 is 'blurred', hide it and show input 1 with the formatted value.

### Html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" readonly data-bind="value: valFormatted, 
                                           visible: !editMode(),
                                           click: toggleEdit" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val, 
                                  visible: editMode, 
                                  hasFocus: editMode,
                                  event: { blur: toggleEdit}" />
</div>
```

### JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var vm = {
        val: ko.observable(),
        valFormatted: ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                // number format
                return (vm.val() || '') + '[formatted]';
            },
            deferEvaluation: true
        }),
        editMode: ko.observable(false),
        toggleEdit: function() {
            vm.editMode(!vm.editMode());
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
};
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var vm = {
  val: ko.observable(),
  valFormatted: ko.computed({
   read: function() {
    // number format
    return (vm.val() || '') + '[formatted]';
   },
   deferEvaluation: true
  }),
  editMode: ko.observable(false),
  toggleEdit: function() {
   vm.editMode(!vm.editMode());
  }
 };

 ko.applyBindings(vm);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: valFormatted, visible: !editMode(), click: toggleEdit" readonly />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: val, visible: editMode, hasFocus: editMode, event: { blur: toggleEdit}" />
</div>
```

Comment: `hasFocus: editMode` i'm not getting focus out if i am trying here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2yg1Lbe7/1/

Comment: Oops placement issue i guess :) we have to place `hasfocus` at-last place in order to get its perfect functionality . Thank you very helpful